# Loop only iterate first 4 rows

Tags: r, loops

My for loop only iterates the first 4 rows of the R dataframe. I read several similar postings and tried suggested approaches but none work. Any help is appreciated

```
df_total <- list()
for (i in 1:length(df_test)) {
    df <- recover(df_test[i,], "PI", 1)
    df$i <-i  
    df_total[[i]] <- df 
 }

big_data = do.call(rbind, df_total)


            row_1   row_2   correct incorrect newrow1   newrow2
  56245270  8549    9949      71       3       8550      9950
   9332380  896     9949      71       1       897       9950
   14783792 1460    4943      70       2       1461      4944
   41437670  4943   10388     70       0       4944      10389
   9323891  896     1460      70       2       897        1461
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `length(df)` gives you the number of columns of a data.frame. If you want the number of rows, use `nrow(df)`.

Ideally you would use

```
seq(nrow(df))
```

to generate an index for a for loop, looping over the rows of a data.frame.